# How to display a selected date and a number in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qdate

I'm currently working with the QCalendarWidget and I need some ideas to accomplish the following.

What would be the best way to add the selecteDate from a QCalendarWidget and a number to some sort of table. What I want is basically to have a list of dates with a number attached to each date, these numbers will be added together and the result will be displayed in a QLabel, I also want to be able to delete rows and again update the QLabel every time a row is deleted.

I also want to be able to save the list to an external file.

Should I use a QStringListModel or a QTableView?

How would you accomplish this?

I'm not expecting any code just a general procedure.

Please see the attached image for more details.

[image: QCalendarWidget]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Should I use a QStringListModel or a QTableView?*

You may want to familiarize yourself with the model/view framework. To put it simply, a model is the actual data that you have and it is independent of how it should be displayed. A view is a particular display implementation of a model. So you could use a model like the QStandarItemModel to store your String+number data and display the model in a QTableView.

Model/View Tutorial from Qt website [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html)
QStandardItemModel class [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html). Has a simple example inside there.

And, for writing and reading the data to a file, I suggest you could use the QXmlStreamWriter/Reader classes. Refer to [Qt xmlWriter/xmlReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898567/qt-xmlwriter-xmlreader)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry I meant to say QStringListModel and a QTableView, but yes in general I'm still learning MVC. Thanks a lot for your suggestions, I will look into it and give it a try.

Comment: I was learning all this not very long ago, and always having doubts of which class to use for a particular data, so I understand. You get the hang of it after a while.

By the way, QStandardItemModel is more suited than the QStringListModel since you have more than just the string to store per entry.